# Trouble linking javascript to html button

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am making a 10-second countdown for a game using Javascript/HTML. At this time the code runs at load. But, the thing is I am having trouble linking it to a button so that I can have the code fire off onclick.

```js
function countdown(secs,elem){
 var element= document.getElementById(elem);
 element.innerHTML = "Time is running out.." +secs+ " seconds";

 secs--;
 var timer = setTimeout('countdown('+secs+' ,"'+elem+'")',1000);

 if (secs<1) {
 clearTimeout(timer);
 element.innerHTML="<h1> GAME OVER!</h1>";
 };
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
 <div id="status"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">countdown(10,"status");</script>
</div>
```

I have tried a lot of different thing but just can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function countdown(secs, elem) {
   var element = document.getElementById(elem);
   element.innerHTML = "Time is running out.." + secs + " seconds";

   secs--;
   var timer = setTimeout('countdown(' + secs + ' ,"' + elem + '")', 1000);

   if (secs < 1) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     element.innerHTML = "<h1> GAME OVER!</h1>";
   };
 }
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div id="status"></div>
  <button onclick="countdown(10,'status');">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no button and event ;)

Comment: When the execution reaches `countdown(10,"status");` in the OP's code, shouldn't the function be called?

Comment: it does execute on load and its mentioned in the question. 'At this time the code runs at load. But, the thing is I am having trouble linking it to a button so that I can have the code fire off onclick.'

Comment: Oh ok. But why don't I see the output when running the OP's code?

Comment: I see the 'countdown not defined' error on page, maybe an body onload would have helped here, but I am assuming the code works on his computer as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) for refrence

```js
function countdown(secs, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Time is running out.." + secs + " seconds";

  secs--;
  var timer = setTimeout('countdown(' + secs + ' ,"' + elem + '")', 1000);

  if (secs < 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    element.innerHTML = "<h1> GAME OVER!</h1>";
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div id="status"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="countdown(10,'status')">start</button>
```